# Разная высота UITableViewCell в UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, ios7

Здравствуйте. 
Будет ли нормально отображаться таблица, у которой каждая ячейка (UITableViewCell) имеет свой собственный размер, отличный от других?

Comment: @devnikor, вы извините конечно, но неужели трудно затестить, прежде чем создавать такие вопросы??? Потратить каких то пять мин, так нет же, лучше недовопрос создать))) имхо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@devnikor](/users/10603/devnikor)](/users/10603/devnikor) да